# KnockoutJs template and multiple nested accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, knockout-2.0

I am struggling with a problem related to multiple nested Twitter Boostrap3(TB3) accordion (or perhaps more appropriate KnockoutJs and templates (or maybe this is a trivial HTML problem)). The attached jsFiddle shows the problem in the second level of the accordion. When a City or a Person is opened, and the opposite is already opened, the one that was already opened is not closed automatically. For all other levels this works fine.

In the code, the problem is located in the two templates and specifically the "data-parent" and the use of "parentAccordionRef". The value of this variable points to an id outside the template. This is not working. Any suggestion?

[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/steingpedersen/Phehb/)

```
<div class="panel-group" id="titleAccordion">
    <!-- ko foreach: Companies -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#titleAccordion" data-bind="attr: { href: '#companyDetails' + companyId }">
                    <span data-bind="html: name"></span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'companyDetails' + companyId }" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-group" data-bind="attr: { id: 'detailsCompany' + companyId }">
                    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'allPersons', data: { Persons: Persons, companyId: companyId, parentAccordionRef: '#detailsCompany' + companyId } }"></div>
                    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'allCities', data: { Cities: Cities, companyId: companyId, parentAccordionRef: '#detailsCompany' + companyId } }"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script id="allPersons" type="text/html">

    <!-- ko if: Persons -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="attr: { href: '#allPersonsTitle' + $parent.companyId, 'data-parent': $data.parentAccordionRef }">
                    <span>Persons</span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'allPersonsTitle' + $parent.companyId }" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-group" data-bind="attr: { id: 'personsGroup' + $parent.companyId }">
                    <!-- ko foreach: Persons -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                                   data-bind="attr: { href: '#personDetail' + personId, 'data-parent': '#personsGroup' + $parent.companyId }">
                                    <span data-bind="html: name"></span>
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'personDetail' + personId }" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <span>Person details</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>

<script id="allCities" type="text/html">
    <!-- ko if: Cities -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="attr: { href: '#allCitiesTitle' + $parent.companyId, 'data-parent': parentAccordionRef }">
                    <span>Cities</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'allCitiesTitle' + $parent.companyId }" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-group" data-bind="attr: { id: 'citiesGroup' + $parent.companyId }">
                    <!-- ko foreach: Cities -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="attr: { href: '#cityDetail' + cityId, 'data-parent': '#citiesGroup' + $parent.companyId }">
                                    <span data-bind="html: name"></span>
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'cityDetail' + cityId }" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <span>City details</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>

<script>
    $(function () {

        var viewModel = {
            Companies: ko.observableArray([
                {
                    companyId: 1, name: 'Detox co', range: 1,
                    Persons: [{ personId: 1, name: 'Mr Mr', address: 'street 1' },
                              { personId: 2, name: 'Mrs Mrs', address: 'street 1' }],
                    Cities: [{ cityId: 1, name: 'London', address: 'street 1' },
                              { cityId: 2, name: 'Paris', address: 'street 1' }]

                },
                {
                    companyId: 2, name: 'Toxic world co', range: 2,
                    Persons: [{ personId: 3, name: 'Mr Green', address: 'street 2' },
                              { personId: 4, name: 'Mrs Green', address: 'street 2' }],
                    Cities: [{ cityId: 3, name: 'Madrid', address: 'street 1' },
                             { cityId: 4, name: 'Munchen', address: 'street 1' }]
                }
            ])
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: spent a little bit on it, the layout looks right, verified spellings match, checked id variables, checked class names, it all looks right to me and matches other areas of the code performing the same, probably something small but unfortunately i could not identify anything myself, just letting you know 2nd pair of eyes checked it out :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is a result of an extra `div` between your `panel-group` and its contents.  This extra `div` is created as a result of using the `template`.  The placeholder of the `template` is still present after it replaces its contents.

You can reproduce this by adding an extra `div` between any of the *working* accordions in your example.

Unfortunately, the solution would be to not use templates.

---

### Edit

You can use container-less template binding. (I just learned this myself!)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Phehb/15/)

Try replacing:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'allPersons', data: { Persons: Persons, companyId: companyId, parentAccordionRef: '#detailsCompany' + companyId } }"></div>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'allCities', data: { Cities: Cities, companyId: companyId, parentAccordionRef: '#detailsCompany' + companyId } }"></div>
```

With:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'allPersons', data: { Persons: Persons, companyId: companyId, parentAccordionRef: '#detailsCompany' + companyId } } -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko template: { name: 'allCities', data: { Cities: Cities, companyId: companyId, parentAccordionRef: '#detailsCompany' + companyId } } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Figures, good job man, I was thinking about ripping out the templating and trying it but didn't want to futz with it lol.

Comment: @Tony I did just that to figure it out myself ;)